# How to three sections in UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uipickerview, ios8

I have sample code of `UIPickerView` with one sections with integer value. How I can make 3 sections with different values - integer, string, etc.? And how I can handle `didSelectRow` method for 3 sections?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var tF1: UITextField!

var progPicker=UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    progPicker.frame=CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 162)
    progPicker.delegate=self
    progPicker.tag = 101
    progPicker.selectRow(180, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    self.view.addSubview(progPicker)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 250
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String
{
    return "\(row)"
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    println("Selected row: \(row)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. Typically components are like section in table view and rows are the rows. The didSelect delegate method passes the component and rows selected, so you could find the particular data from your model which was actually selected. Here is a small sample,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300))

    view.addSubview(pickerView)
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
  }

  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
    return 3
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    if component == 0{
      return "Int: \(row)"
    }else if component == 1{
      return "String: \(row)"
    }

    return "Other: \(row)"

  }

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == 0{
      println("Int component: \(row) selected")
    }else if component == 1{
      println("String component: \(row) selected")

    }else{
      println("Other component: \(row) selected")

    }
  }

}
```

If you wish to customize the picker view, you could use the following delegates.

```
– pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:
– pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
```

Comment: Can I customize UIPickerView - color, font, background, etc.?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. You could also use the custom view of your own.

Comment: With method `viewForRow`?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the solution first of all. I was wondering what you would o if you had 2 uipickerviews. One with 1 component and one with 3 components. is there a way to distinguish which uipickerview is selected and therefore only have one set of picker functions or do we need two sets? (by picker functions i mean the 4 that you need to make the conform to the delegate)

Comment: @AceGreen Hi Ace, it is quite easy even if you have number of PickerView, you can simply keep property of the two different picker views.
Like create two properties, countrySelectionPickerView and colorSelectionPicker. Now when the delegate or datasource methods are triggered, the method also pass you the pickerview, you can then compare if the passed picker view is one of the countrySelectionPickerView or colorSelectionPickerView and react accordingly. Hope you got my point. Write to me if you still have anything